# What set of units does the Orion capsule cockpit instrumention use?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, design, unit-systems

Shuttle was English, ISS is metric.

What's Orion?

For example: What units are inertial velocity displayed in?

Comment: English? Do you mean Imperial?

Comment: I mean English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Engineering_units

Comment: Huh. Well I learned something.

Comment: don't worry, I'm sure that after Brexit we'll move back to the crazy units too, so it'll make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the decision of NASA from January 8, 2007 to use only metric units for all operations on the lunar surface when it returns to the Moon is still valid, it should be valid for the Orion capsule too. See this [page](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2007/08jan_metricmoon).

ISS seems to be not pure metric:

> NASA has ostensibly used the metric system since about 1990, the
>   statement said, but English units are still employed on some missions,
>   and a few projects use both. NASA uses both English and metric aboard
>   the International Space Station.

from [space.com](https://www.space.com/3332-nasa-finally-metric.html)

Here is an image of a Orion cockpit display design from this [NASA paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110013203.pdf):

[image]

We see non metric units here like ft, ft/s, nmi. But there is also the string **UNITS English**. This might indicate user selectable units by a soft key **UNITS metric/English**.

Comment: Agreed, Item 11 looks like a units switching entry. Nice find!